# JasperPHP error "Your report has an error and couldn't be processed! ...."

Tags: php, laravel, jasper-reports, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to generate reports using JasperPHP library in my laravel application and facing the error:

> Exception in JasperPHP.php line 178: Your report has an error and
>   couldn't be processed! Try to output the command using the function
>   `output();` and run it manually in the console.

My php code:

```
$database = array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'database'  => 'infolady_service',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
    );
    $output = public_path() . '/report/'.time().'_codelution';
    $ext = "pdf";

    $jasper = new JasperPHP;
    // Compile a JRXML to Jasper
    $jasper->compile(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jrxml')->execute();

    // Process a Jasper file to PDF and RTF (you can use directly the .jrxml)
    $jasper->process(
        __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/hello_world.jasper',     //.jasper file link
        $output,                                                                    //Output location
        array($ext),                                                                //Extension name
        array(),                                                                    //Any parameter as variable
        $database,                                                                  //DB informations
        false,                                                                      
        false
    )->execute();
```

Comment: Have you tried preview in iReport?, what is the error?, we need more detail of  error and source of .jrxml to be able to help you.